# Vue2 + Vuex - not rendering array that is set successfully in store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to render 209,579 options and I think that I am not using Vuex lifecycle + axios correctly

- I see all options set in store state via Vuex in console.
- No errors are displayed
- Options are empty and not rendering the state `cityNames`array
- `main.js` is exporting store to all components

I think I am not applying this lifecycle correctly, where I should use getters here, can someone bring order to my lifecycle?

#### store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
        isTrue: true,
        cityNames: [],
    },

    getters:{
        getCityNames(state){
            return state.cityNames;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SetCityNames(state, cityNames){
            state.cityNames = cityNames
    },
    actions: {
        loadData({commit}){
            axios.get('http://localhost:3000/allCities')
                .then(function (response) {
                    commit('SetCityNames', response.data)
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
            });

        }
    },
});
```

#### script

```
export default {
    name: "Weather",
    methods: {
        allCityNames() {
            this.$store.dispatch('loadData')
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.allCityNames();
    }
}
```

#### template

```
<select>
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="cityName in $store.cityNames">{{cityName}}</option>
</select>
```

Thanks,
Bud

Comment: looks right, though maybe it's not detecting the change in data correctly. Maybe try `state.cityNames = [...cityNames]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed my code to be executed from compute, only to find out the error (at last!) which was: `maximum stacksize exceeded`, at this point I understood that Vue is not letting me render such a huge array (209,579 items) into view.

### part I - Code Change:

I have created an isLoaded state that is set to `true` once axios commits it's response,

> I'm still not sure if this is the best method due to the async nature of axios's call, it could have not finished with `commit('SetCityNames', response.data);` and right after invoking the commit, it would invoke the next : `commit('changeLoadedState');`

so i've added to state:`isLoaded: false`

added a getter: `didItLoad(state){return state.isLoaded}`

added a mutation: `changeLoadedState(state){state.isLoaded = true}`

added a commit (`commit('changeLoadedState');`) to my axios call in actions:

```
loadData({commit}) {
            axios.get('http://localhost:3000/allCities')
                .then(function (response) {
                    commit('SetCityNames', response.data);
                    commit('changeLoadedState');
                }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

In my component I am still dispatching the axios call in methods since it being called first, and added a `computed` method for the render side, as follows:

```
computed:{
          isLoaded(){
              return this.$store.getters.didItLoad;
          },
            renderCities(){
                return this.$store.getters.getCityNames;

            }
        }
```

In My rendered template I first check with my select the loaded status and only then populate the options:

```
<select v-if="isLoaded">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="cityName in renderCities">{{cityName}}</option>
</select>
```

### Part II - Change Payload Size

So after setting my code straight, I went into my node express server and changed my route's loop to stop at 1000 items, and all worked great.

At this point I was curious what happens what happens if I start adding zeroes, so at 10K items, takes 1-2 sec to load options, opening the dropdown starts to show signs of latency due to stress, at 50K items it takes around 5 seconds to open the dropdown.

### Bottom Line

The issue is not the size of the array, Vuex works amazing, getting a 209,579 item array in ~800ms which included backend parsing by Express.js (my whole stack is local so no network latency).

I will try to create an autocomplete that would start listing from 2nd or 3rd character.

Thanks to replying members.

Answer (score 1):

You have a getters named `getCityNames`.It is `$store.getters.getCityNames` not `$store.cityNames`.

So change

```
<option v-for="cityName in $store.cityNames">{{cityName}}</option>
```

to

```
<option v-for="cityName in $store.getters.getCityNames">{{cityName}}</option>
```

it would be better to refactor to use a computed property rather than inlining in the template.

```
<option v-for="cityName in cityNames">{{cityName}}</option>

//script
computed: {
    cityNames() {
        return this.$store.getters.getCityNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great and thanks, ill try when i get back and check if works.
Overall, would populating 200k+ in an option dropdown be the only route to take here? Maybe autocomplete from store with a `handleChange ()` would be a good route to take without 200k options.

Comment: @clusterBuddy populating with more than 200k  options does not look like it would perform well as the options will not be populated until the for loop completes. It would be better if you create a custom compponent that loads 50 options at a time and lazyloads the next 50 options. But that too does not  seem good as who will scroll  through 200k options. So Its betters you inncorporate some search and autocomplete functionality tto load up the options.as done in vuetify - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#example-custom-filter

Comment: Hey vamsi, I have changed as you advised and still not receiving a render to option table, as I am not getting ANY error to this, is there a way to debug this?

Comment: @clusterBuddy when do you call the `allCityNames` method (which populate your getter) ? maybe you just need to call the action `loadData` from the store when your component is mounted, not in a method...

Comment: @sovalina - changed and put in mounted `this.allCityNames();` that does the dispatch: `this.$store.dispatch('loadData')`, and no juice :(

Comment: @clusterBuddy do you have the Vue devtools extension in your browser ? to check if the data is well loaded when you call your `allCityNames` method

Comment: @clusterBuddy Well, i tried your code in a fiddle and it actually works : [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sovalina/xekwLyh6/4/)  
So maybe there is a conflict elsewhere or a syntax error...

Comment: @sovalina I have found the issue, long answer below :D